# Error with upload image to amazon in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8

I try upload a file to amazon. The next code works fine in iOS7:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *putRequest = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:fileThumbanilName inBucket:bucketName];
putRequest.credentials = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
putRequest.filename = [_pathThumbnailToUpload lastPathComponent];
putRequest.endpoint = s3.endpoint;

// sign the request (also computes md5 checksums etc.)
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [s3 signS3Request:putRequest];
NSMutableURLRequest* request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:request.URL];
[request2 setHTTPMethod:request.HTTPMethod];
[request2 setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[request allHTTPHeaderFields]];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = nil;
    sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:_pathThumbnailToUpload];

_sessionUploadThumbnail = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
uploadThumbanilTask = [_sessionUploadThumbnail uploadTaskWithRequest:request2 fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_pathThumbnailToUpload] ];

[uploadThumbanilTask resume];
```

But, when I run the app in iOS8, the method "didReceiveChallenge" is called infinite times and request never finish.
Also, if i change from background session to default, then the code works fine. This problem is with a background session but I don't find solution.

Comment: Could you show your `didRecieveChallenge` code?

Comment: - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"session did receive challenge");
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
}